# What is the actual address of My Computer

Tags: windows-10, cortana

I am developing an artificial intelligence for Windows and I am trying to map the voice input "Open My Computer" to the actual opening of My Computer by the bot. For that, I require the actual address of it.

Example of actual address of C drive: `C:\`

My code:

```
case "My Computer":
                    listBox2.Items.Add(e.Result.Text.ToString());
                    speakText("One moment.");
                    Process pr1 = new Process();
                    pr1.StartInfo.FileName = "Here will be My PC path";
                    pr1.Start();
                    break;
```

Comment: What language? Also, the folks over at StackOverflow might be able to answer your question better

Comment: developing in visual studio with c# is the language.

Comment: Issues specific to programming and software development are off topic, see [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try [SO] but please first read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Rainmeter help](https://docs.rainmeter.net/tips/launching-windows-special-folders/), you can launch “My Computer” using the following “path”:

```
::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}
```

The list also contains a lot of other special folders that may be of interest.

Your code would look like this:

```
Process pr1 = new Process();
pr1.StartInfo.FileName = "::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}";
pr1.Start();
```

Comment: sir the code is not able to compile if i enter the hex value.

Comment: You made a mistake then. It’s still a string of course, so it needs to be enclosed in double quotes.

Comment: It worked! sir can you tell me what mistake i was doing, when i was using like pr.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\"; it was going fine but not with My computer?

Comment: I don’t know what you wrote that didn’t compile, so no – I cannot tell you what was wrong, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The "My Computer" location is NOT a path/folder in the normal sense.
As such you can not open it as a path/folder via the normal mechanisms to access files or folders.
In your case it is even worse as you attempt to open a process from an executable. This isn't an executable at all.

What you need to to is open "Explorer.exe" and give "::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}" via command-line parameter as "starting location" for the explorer.exe process. This will instruct Explorer to show you the "My Computer" view.